# Error:cannot launch node [octomap_server/octomap_server_node]

Tags: ros, octomap, 3dmapping, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am trying to convert my point cloud data into map using octomap. I am newbie in this, so i would like to know what I am doing wrong.
To create map these are steps I followed:

1. `rosbag info<mypoint_cloudbagfile>` : OUTPUT: gives all the required information appropriately
2. `rosbag play <mypoint_cloudbagfile>`
3. Created my own Package
4. Inside launch folder added this data: https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/blob/master/octomap_server/launch/octomap_mapping.launch
5. Updated Package.xml with required dependencies
6. Updated `CmakeLists.tx`t like this:

   ```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
    project(octomap_server)



    set(PACKAGE_DEPENDENCIES
      roscpp
      rospy
      std_msgs
      pcl_ros
      pcl_conversions
      visualization_msgs
      nav_msgs
      octomap_ros
      octomap_msgs
      #dynamic_reconfigure
      nodelet
      sensor_msgs
    )


    find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${PACKAGE_DEPENDENCIES})

    find_package(PCL REQUIRED QUIET COMPONENTS common sample_consensus io segmentation filters)

    find_package(octomap REQUIRED)

    include_directories(
     include
     $(catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS)
        $(PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS)
     $(OCTOMAP_INCLUDE_DIRS)
       )
       catkin_package(
         INCLUDE_DIRS include
         LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
      CATKIN_DEPENDS ${PACKAGE_DEPENDENCIES}
      DEPENDS octomap PCL
    )

    set(LINK_LIBS
        ${OCTOMAP_LIBRARIES}
           ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
    )
   ```
7. ran launch file :

   ```
    roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping.launch
   ```

It runs but gives this error:

```
OUTPUT: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [octomap_server/octomap_server_node]: can't locate node [octomap_server_node] in package [octomap_server]
```

P.S.: I have already installed octomap_mapping using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-octomap_mapping
```

Please tell me why this error occurs and how can I repair it to proceed in creating a map.

There are some solutions I tried:

1. run `rosrun octomap_server octomap_server_node` to check node

I got this output:

```
Couldn't find executable named octomap_server_node below /home/ubuntu/catkin/src/octomap_server
```

2. Source the bash file using:

   source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270186/error:cannot-launch-node-%5Boctomap_server/octomap_server_node%5D/) by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-04**:
Welcome. I edited your question to make it more readable. In the future, please format any terminal output/source code/etc. using the `101010` button to make it more readable.

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-05**:
Thanx a lot.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-08**:
Are modifying the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` of the package that you downloaded? If so, why? Also, did you run `catkin_make` from the root for your workspace? I don't see that step listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question pops up quite regularly and the solution is usually the same, `source` the `setup.bash` file:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Where `catkin_ws` is your catkin workspace. You can always Google the error to find a solution before posting a question:

https://www.google.com/search?q=OUTPUT%3A+ERROR%3A+cannot+launch+node+of+type+site%3Aanswers.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-05**:
Using Google to search ROS Answers is a good suggestion.

My suggestion: add `site:answers.ros.org` to the query. That will limit results to just this site.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-05**:
Good call. I updated the query to limit results to this site.

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-05**:
@Jayess : I have already done that. My workspace bash file is already sourced. I googled the answer for this error and couldn't get the correct solution. that's why i thought of posting new question since it might be issue in Octomap_maping.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-05**:
@Eyshika: Without that information people are going to give to you the most common solution to that problem. Please update your question with what you have tried and what the results were.

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-07**:
@jayess: I have updated my query. please check .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the exact problem and here is what I did to resolve it on ros kinetic:

1. Run (to install ros octomap packages):
   sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-octomap ros-kinetic-octomap-mapping ros-kinetic-octomap-msgs ros-kinetic-octomap-ros ros-kinetic-octomap-rviz-plugins ros-kinetic-octomap-server
2. Rebuild your workspace (i.e catkin_make)

---

Originally posted by [meadows](https://answers.ros.org/users/39467/meadows/) with karma: 31 on 2019-04-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-04-29**:
I had same problem and your answer solved that, thank you